# Invoking a Backgrid from another

Tags: backgrid

I'm in backgrid 1, where I've rowclick event enabled, now I want to invoke a refresh of another grid based on the click.

Two ways I'm thinking a. The row click event handler does the .get and passes the data to the collection of another grid b. Modify the url of the another grid collection , and then call the refresh on that grid.
Any pointers pls?

Comment: I would use b, it is always a good practise to let the collection in a grid to fetch data itself, instead of .get the data, and pass in to that collection.

Comment: If you are well versed with it, could you post an example ?